# systeminfo command in wine

Tags: macos, batch-file, cmd, wine

I tried to install a windows app in my mac through wine. The install file is an bat file called **installProcessDesigner_admin.bat** but when I try to install with

```
wine cmd 
>>installProcessDesigner_admin.bat
```

I got this message

```
Can't recognize 'SYSTEMINFO  ' as an internal or external command, or batch script.
```

How to get this command in wine?

Comment: You would probably be better off asking this at http://serverfault.com.

Comment: `systeminfo` is a Windows application found under `c:\windows\system32`.  Wine doesn't support all of the applications that come with Windows, it simply provides the DLL support for Windows applications to think they are running on a Windows operating system.

Comment: You might analyze the batch file to see what information it is using from running the `systeminfo` program and determine if it is even needed in order to install the app.  If it isn't needed, you could simply comment out that line in the batch file by placing the word `REM ` in front of that line.  If it is needed, you might try copying `systeminfo.exe` from a Windows machine to your Mac/Wine environment and see if it is able to use it, although that may be problematic since `systeminfo` shows the Windows OS config, including service packs (it probably won't run properly on Mac/Wine).

Answer (score 0):

Wine has a very limited number of commands on the DOS prompt. Type `HELP` into the prompt to see a list.
If you want more commands, you will have to copy the [command].exe files in the System32 folder on a windows machine.